# Rails 3.1, Apache2, Passenger cannot load plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i am trying to make my application work on Apache2+Passenger. I've done so in the past, but seems that a few things have changed. After installing everything and runnnig some tasks, i try to access my webpage and get :

```
undefined local variable or method `is_private_message' for #<Class:0x00000003764fa0>
```

which seems to show that simple_private_messages (an external plugin) has not been loaded. The plugin files are there and the whole app works fine under the standard rails server in my local pc.

I've tried restarting apache several times, but i still get the same message. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the plugin was ignored by git since it was another git repository*sigh*. Simply 'rails install plugin' fixes it.